# Current Location of user on Map In android

Tags: android

I am trying to display current location of user on Map,
But it not success till now, Can anyone help me to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MyLocationsOverlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html). Here is an example of it's use: http://blogs.itemis.de/frey/2009/04/04/location-based-services-on-android-part-1/

Comment: Hi according to your help I done my job, The code which I use is as follow,

Answer (score 0):

By using following code I got latitude & longitude of current location, and pass this values of latitude & longitude to Map. Then it shows current location.

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    location=new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double lat=location.getLatitude();
    double lng=location.getLongitude();
    }
```

Thanks for all help.